# magento 2 : which tables is used while creating configurable product

Tags: magento2, database, configurable-product, magento-2.1.3

when i am creating configurable Product from admin, i want to know in which table the entry related to configurable product is stored.

Answer (score 12):

Configurable products manage by below tables

`catalog_product_super_attribute :` holds the configurable attributes.

`catalog_product_super_attribute_label :` holds the store view labels for the configurable attributes.

`catalog_product_super_link :` holds child and parent product relation.

Comment: can its used **catalog_product_relation** table ?

Answer (score 4):

Below tables are using for Configurable  product

- `catalog_product_super_attribute`
- `catalog_product_super_attribute_label`
- `catalog_product_super_link`

Comment: can its used **catalog_product_relation** table ?