# Assoicated Products relation with Main Products, SQL Query

Tags: magento-1.9, database, query, join-table, associated-products

Our magento store products have three drop downs like color, size & weight. The price of main product changes when we select from size or weight etc. Stuck to run a query to get assoicated products data. Ideally need a query but if you have answer of any these please comment below, cheers

1. Question 1: How magento uses relation(column names, product id etc ) between main product and associated items and in which tables data store etc.?
2. Question 2: By using mysql query, how can I pull out data using unique product id (attribute_id or SKU).

Comment: what type  of main product configurable/Grouped/bundle?

Comment: mostly configurable

Comment: no one dealt issue like this?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/190762/4564